# Paypal IPN - undefined index error

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm getting 'undefined index' back for any post I try and assign to a variable from the Paypal form fields, example:  $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];

If I hard code it $item_number = 1; then it works.

I'm using Micah Carrick script below: Any ideas why this is happening?

```
<?php
/*
ipn.php - example code used for the tutorial:

PayPal IPN with PHP
How To Implement an Instant Payment Notification listener script in PHP
http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html

(c) 2011 - Micah Carrick
*/

// tell PHP to log errors to ipn_errors.log in this directory
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');

// intantiate the IPN listener
include('ipnlistener.php');
$listener = new IpnListener();

// tell the IPN listener to use the PayPal test sandbox
$listener->use_sandbox = true;

// try to process the IPN POST
try {
    $listener->requirePostMethod();
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    exit(0);
}

if ($verified) {


$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$to = "myEmail@blah.com";
$subject = "Paypal IPN Test";
$message = "Email sent successfully";
$message .= $item_number;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$listener->getTextReport());


} 
else {
// manually investigate the invalid IPN
mail('myEmail@blah.com', 'Invalid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`item_number` only exists if you pass an item number through to Paypal in the order. Consider it a product ID or a SKU.

If you don't need an identifier for your product, skip it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the info, the problem was I was using Paypal cart and the variable needs to be $item_number1 = $_POST['item_number1']; Now I need to find a way of looping through the item_numbers. Need these for identifying the productID in the database. Paypal is very poor when it comes to what variables you can use to work with. I need to match an 'id' and also pass a new quantity but NOT the paypal quantity.....so need to use another Paypal form field to get that. I did try with the 'custom' field but even a cart only allows one 'custom' field......Paypal = very poor.